# DataTable to xml without the tablename or the tablename as the root

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, datatable

Hi I realise that this question has popped up over time, however I cannot find what I am looking for. Basically I want to convert the data in a DataTable to xml. I have done this successfully using the writexml procedure, however I now have another requirement which requires me to list our the IDs in an xml format. Again I can do this via the writexml proc however, each row is listed as the tablename tag so I end up with the following.

```
<DataSet>
  <tablename>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </tablename>
  <tablename>
    <ID>2</ID>
  </tablename>
  <tablename>
    <ID>3</ID>
  </tablename>
</DataSet>
```

What I want however is the following

```
<DataSet>
  <tablename>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ID>3</ID>
  </tablename>
</DataSet>
```

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this without looping through the datatable to create an XML manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the above already generated xml to modify to the required format using XML Linq

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load("1.xml");
    var coll = document.Descendants("ID");
    var merged = new XDocument(
        new XElement("DataSet", new XElement("tablename", coll))
    );
    merged.Save("1.xml");
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to work, by the way the ml is not in a file it is in a string which then gets produced.

Comment: You can use XDocument.Parse if the xml is in a string format

Comment: but how do i save it aka merged.save

Comment: Hi would just like to comment to say that in the end I converted merged to a string and it all works.